# Nested filtering with Angular.js version 1.2.18

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, version

I'm experimenting with AngularJS for the first time. I do repeat a template based on JSON data, which here is a sample:

```
$scope.users = [
    {name: 'first user', status: {name: 'employee'}},
    {name: 'second user', status: {name: 'freelancer'}},
    {name: 'third user', status: {name: 'employee'}},
];
```

This works fine:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</p>
```

Now I want to prefilter the users displayed. Works fine, too:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status: 'employee'}">{{user.name}}</p>
```

But when I want to filter on the basis of JSON data within a nested object (`status.name` instead of `status`), it does not work anymore!

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status.name: 'employee'}">{{user.name}}</p>
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.18. If I use an older version, like AngularJS 1.2.0-rc.3, it works again.

I can't find any information in the documentation about that behaviour. 
Is there a new syntax or is the feature just not implemented anymore?

Comment: Plunker availible: http://plnkr.co/edit/VrANi4X4u8hULZYTSN36?p=preview 

Change the version of AngularJS to v.1.2.18 and see that it does not work anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a breaking change introduces in [AngularJS 1.2.11](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/339a1658cd9bfa5e322a01c45aa0a1df67e3a842). It [has been decided](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/6009#issuecomment-33786279) to not mark it as such, because it was not a tested nor a documented behaviour.

Since this release, `myObject | filter:{'key.subkey':'search'}` will search the string `search` into `myObject['key.subkey']` and no more in `myObject['key']['subkey']`.

A new syntax was introduced in [AngularJS 1.2.13](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b4eed8ad94ce9719540462c1ee969dfd3c6b2355), which seems to me more natural, to search in nested object: `myObject | filter:{key : {subkey : 'search'}}`. That's the solution you're looking for.

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status : {name: 'employee'}}">{{user.name}}</p>
```

Comment: perfect. that's exactly the information i was looking for. brakets based filtering works for me with AngularJS v1.2.18