# AngularJS filter list on sub element in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create a simple AngularJS filter on a list.  However the element I want to filter on is a sub-element in an array.

([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ed4becky/vQAJy/20/))

The objects:

```
elements = [{
    'claim': [{value:'foo'}],
    class: 'class1',
    subject: 'name1'
}, {
    'claim':  [{value:'bar'}],
    class: 'class1',
    subject: 'name2'
}, {
    'claim':  [{value:'baz'}],
    class: 'class1',
    subject: 'name2'
}, {
    'claim':  [{value:'quux'}],
    class: 'class1',
    subject: 'name3'
}];
```

HTML:

```
<tr class='claimrow' 
    data-ng-repeat='c in elements | filter:{claim[0].value:srcBoxFilter} | orderBy: "claim[0].value" '>
```

The order by handles the syntax "claim[0].value" but the filter does not.

This generates an error:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [:] 
at column 25 of the expression 
[elements | filter:{claim[0].value:srcBoxFilter} | orderBy: "claim[0].value"] 
starting at [[0].value:srcBoxFilter} | orderBy: "claim[0].value"].
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested filtering with Angular.js version 1.2.18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266784/nested-filtering-with-angular-js-version-1-2-18)

Comment: This is different because of the introduction of the array.  I have tried filter:{claim:[{value:srcBoxFilter}]} but that does not seem to work (Although the error disappears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Especially because the nested array value works for ordering but not filtering. I had a play with your JSFiddle and couldn't get anything out of the box working. You could get around this very easily by writing your own filter.

I've [updated your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQAJy/23/) to show how you could do this. The only changes I made to your code are shown below:

**JavaScript**

```
myApp.filter('byFirstClaimValue', function () {
    return function (items, filterText) {
        if(!filterText)
            return items;

        var out = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].claim[0].value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                out.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="claimrow" data-ng-repeat="c in elements | byFirstClaimValue:srcBoxFilter | orderBy: 'claim[0].value'">
```

Comment: I knew creating my own was an option, but thought there should be an 'out of the box' solution.  Or at least an inline function solution

Comment: Yea, it seems like what you had should've worked given that the order works... +1'd your question :)