# ng-table filter with nested properties

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have following JSON:

```
  [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Data": {"Str1": "Ann", "Str2": "Xenna"}
  },{
    "Id": "2",
    "Data": {"Str1": "Bob","Str2": "Bobby"},
  }]
```

And I created ng-table to display it. I tried to add filter. When I filter by Id everything works as expected (filter is `{ "Id": "2" }`). But I cannot create proper filter do `Str1` and `Str2` fields. I already tried:

1. `{ "Str1": "A" }`
2. `{ "Data.Str1": "A" }`
3. `{ "Data['Str1']": "A" }`

but above options does not work.

Example of my work is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/MyJCqTlgvKLtSP63FYQY?p=preview

**Update**

Thanks to @Blackhole I founded that filter `{Data: {Str1: 'A'}}` works. But I can only delcare this in code. When I try to put something like this in HTML it doesn't even show filter:

```
  <td data-title="'Str1'" filter="{Data:{Str1: 'text'}}">
    {{ user.Data.Str1 }}
  </td>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `{Data: {Str1: 'A'}}`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266784/nested-filtering-with-angular-js-version-1-2-18

Comment: @Blackhole Your code works from script, but doesn't when it is in html. I will add update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to use `filter="{Data:{Str1: 'text'}}"` in html,input doesn't showing cause of template in header,have a look in [source code](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/ng-table/header.html#L18).

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, filter) in column.filter"> //!!!! right here it's not supported
        <div ng-if="column.filterTemplateURL" ng-show="column.filterTemplateURL">
            <div ng-include="column.filterTemplateURL"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!column.filterTemplateURL" ng-show="!column.filterTemplateURL">
            <div ng-include="'ng-table/filters/' + filter + '.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

right here `<div ng-repeat="(name, filter) in column.filter">` it's not dig into nested objects

`Ngtable` not support nested filter in  default template,so you can create your own template,which gonna support it.Have a look to [example of header template](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/18).

#### Note

This how `column.filter` is initializing,it's parsing from `filter` attribute on `td` tag,[source](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/ng-table.js#L565)

```
var parsedAttribute = function (attr, defaultValue) {
                        return function (scope) {
                            return $parse(el.attr('x-data-' + attr) || 
                                          el.attr('data-' + attr) || 
                                          el.attr(attr))
                                (scope, {
                                $columns: columns
                            }) || defaultValue;
                        };
                    };

                    var parsedTitle = parsedAttribute('title', ' '),
                        headerTemplateURL = parsedAttribute('header', false),
                        // here
                        filter = parsedAttribute('filter', false)(),
                        filterTemplateURL = false,
                        filterName = false;

                    ...
                    columns.push({
                        ....
                        filter: filter,
```

Comment: @Garath i am glad to help!!,besides this question is interesting to me too)))

Comment: @KostiaMololkin can you update the broken link? "example of header template."