# ngTable nested fields

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524230/ngtable-filtering-on-nested-fields) and the solution was pretty straightforward, however [this](http://plnkr.co/1yvDy3) plunker doesn't seem to work with Angular 1.33 which I use in my project.

Here is [the same plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3ucerZQLatLvEHez72Q?p=preview) with the issue (only updated Angular to version 1.33) .

**Html**

```
  <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <tr class='listing' ng-repeat="invoice in $data">
      <td data-title="'Invoice No.'" sortable="'no'" filter="{'no':'text'}">
        {{invoice.no}}
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'date'" filter="{'date':'text'}">
        {{invoice.date}}
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Client'" sortable="'client.fullname'" filter="{'client.fullname':'text'}">
        {{invoice.client.fullname}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: If you remove .fullname from the filter it'll use all of the properties of the object (I think) which works.  Will that cause you other problems?

Comment: @DoctorMick I know that... but I need the `full_name` column to be sortable not only searchable... also if I remove the property I won't be able to search in multiple fields in `user` nested object.

Comment: It looks like the filter syntax has been changed to use proper JSON notation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6222.  My guess is that ngTable hasn't been updated accordingly.

Comment: yes I think so..dotted string not parsing correctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741658/4104866 have a look ,ngtable doesnt parse dot at all

Comment: hmm but as he stated in question, that is working fine in older version 1.2.x

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CAnuwofI4J1ZshqVrtA5?p=preview have a look it working in 1.2x but filter is set up with no dots

Comment: u may not set up filter via `prop.prop:text`

Comment: @KostiaMololkin thanx...that was suggested in older comment, unfortunately if I do so I won't be able to sort according to that column; am I?

Comment: @MohammadWalid u can sort but u have to make ur own header template

Comment: @MohammadWalid i mistaken u don't need a template,have a look answer ,is it right for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working with sort and filter,`ngtable 0.3.1` - [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rr9CieFQIGlmYhHxDmbS?p=preview)

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
    <tr class='listing' ng-repeat="invoice in $data">
      <td data-title="'Invoice No.'" sortable="'no'" filter="{'no':'text'}">
        {{invoice.no}}
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'date'" filter="{'date':'text'}">
        {{invoice.date}}
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Client'" sortable="'client.fullname'" filter="{'client':'text'}">
        {{invoice.client.fullname}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanx `Kositia` your solution is working as expected... but I am hoping if there is ability to filter on multiple nested fields... for now this enough for me... thanks again.

Comment: @MohammadWalid i am glad to help, so u would like to filter over all props of client object, right?, it's interesting for me too,i'll gonna make some research on that and come back)))